# Spring @Around Aspect being ignored in one controller but not in other one

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, aspectj, spring-annotations

I have a weird issue - my aspect is ignored in one specific controller, but works in others...

context.xml includes:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<task:annotation-driven />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package.address.aspect"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package.address.controllers" />
```

aspects declaration:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DoWork {
}
```

the aspect itself:

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
public class DoWorkAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(com.my.package.address.aspect.DoWork)")
  public Object doWork(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
      ...
  }
}
```

the controller that the aspect fires on (works):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping")
@Validated
public class PingController {

    @DoWork
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public PingResponse ping(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {
        return new PingResponse("ok");
    }
```

and, the controller that the aspect ignores:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/not_ping")
public class NotPingController
{
    @DoWork
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    protected void notPing(
         @PathVariable("id") String id
         ) throws
            IOException,
            NotAuthorizedException
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So one controller gets ignored while the other works...
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your method **NotPingController.notPing()** is a protected method.

According to [spring's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) "*Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring's AOP framework, protected methods are by definition not intercepted* "

Can you try making that method public and check whether it is been intercepted or not

Comment: Well, this is documentation for an older version of Spring and it was always somewhat incorrect for CGLIB proxies. I happen to know that because I authored the documentation change request which resulted in the [current documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) to be fixed. It now states: _"For JDK proxies, only public interface method calls on the proxy can be intercepted. With CGLIB, public and protected method calls on the proxy are intercepted (and even package-visible methods, if necessary)."_

Comment: Having said that, if you change your configuration so as to use CGLIB proxies you can intercept protected methods. But still, making them public as suggested in this answer is the better way IMO. I just wanted to add unmentioned facts here.